# How to do f = x*y integration as the example I have shown below for f = x

Tags: python-2.7, integration

How to integrate a function f = x*y, lower limit = 0, upper limit = 1, interval = 4 using simpson's rule using simple loops (not using scipy). 
I have done for f = x, which works

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from numpy import exp

# defining function
def f(x):
    return x

num_data_points = 5 
lower_limit = 0
upper_limit = 1
step_size = float(upper_limit - lower_limit) / (num_data_points - 1)
integral = 0
integral = f(lower_limit) * float(step_size) * (float(1)/3)
integral = integral + f(upper_limit) * float(step_size) * (float(1)/3)
current_point = 0

for i in range (1, num_data_points-1):
    current_point = lower_limit + i * float(step_size)

    if i%2 == 0:
        integral = integral + float(step_size) * (float(2)/3) * f(current_point)  
    else:
        integral = integral + float(step_size) * (float(4)/3) * f(current_point)

print (integral)
```